# Given $S = \{1,2,3,...\}$ proving that $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}) = 1$

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Suppose that $S=\{1,2,3,...\}$ is the set of all positive integers and that $P$ is some probability measure on $S$. Prove that we must have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\}) = 1$$

Is my proof correct? 
Suppose $P(s) = 2^{-s}$  for all $s \in S$. Now, note that $A_n = \{1,2 ,3,...,n\}$ increase to $A = \{1,2,3, ..., n\}$. That is, $\{A_n\}$ converges to $A$. Therefore, using continuity of probabilities, it has to be the case that:
$$P(\{1, 2, 3, ...\}) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P(\{1, 2, 3, ..., n\})$$
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}(P(1) + P(2) + P(3) + ... + P(n))$$
$$= \lim_{n \to \infty}(2^{-1} + 2^{-2} + 2^{-3} + ... + 2^{-n})$$
$$= 1$$

Comment: No, it is not correct. All you showed was that the desired claim was true for one particular probability distribution.  You were asked to prove it for *all* probability distributions.

Comment: Could I do so by assigning $P(s)$ to a generic increasing function?

Comment: No.  (and I assume you meant "decreasing", as $2^{-s}$ is a decreasing function).  There is no reason for the distribution to be a decreasing function.

Comment: Your proof works a lot better if you just erase the first sentence and any references to $2^{-n}$.  Continuity of probabilities is all you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out, you have only proven the statement for a particular measure. However, the method you used *does* work for an arbitrary measure. Let $A_n$ be as in your post. Then, $$A_1 \subset A_2 \subset A_3 \subset \cdots.$$

Now, by *continuity of measure*, we have $$P\left(\bigcup_{n \geqslant 1}A_n\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P(A_n).$$

Substituting the values for the above quantities, we get $$P(\{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P(\{1, \ldots, n\}).$$

Answer (score 1):

Theorem: For any measure $P$ and any infinite sequence $\{S_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, we have $P(\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty S_i) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n S_i)$.

Proof: Define $K_{i} = S_{i} \setminus \bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^{i - 1} S_j$. Then we have $\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n K_i = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n S_i$ for all $n$ by induction on $i$. It therefore follows that $K_i \cap K_j = \emptyset$ whenever $i \neq j$, since if $j < i$ then we have $K_j \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^{i - 1} K_j = \bigcup\limits_{j = 1}^{i - 1} S_j$ which has an empty intersection with $K_i$ by definition. It further follows that $\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty K_i = \bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty S_i$. Then we have $P(\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty K_i) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^\infty P(K_i) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n P(K_i) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n K_i) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n S_i)$.

In this case, we define $S_i = \{i\}$. Then $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(\{1, 2, ..., n\}) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} P(\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^n S_i) = P(\bigcup\limits_{i = 1}^\infty S_i) = P(\mathbb{N}) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I just have a quick question, how is it that $P(\mathbb{N}) = 1$? Would that always be the case?

Comment: @user62487108 It's a probability measure, so by the definition of a probability measure, $P(\mathbb{N}) = 1$.